# DAX - Apply Filter If Measure Used In Filter is Not BLANK

Tags: dax

I have the following measure totaling up `TotalGLDetail` with a number of filters on the table, the last one being the issue. All the measures these filters depend on are never `BLANK` except, sometimes, `[MFControl]`

```
TotalMF:=CALCULATE([TotalGLDetail]
    ,FILTER(GLDETAIL,GLDETAIL[concat]=[AnyMFAcct])
    ,FILTER(GLDETAIL,OR(GLDETAIL[journalid]=[MFSrc1],GLDETAIL[journalid]=[MFSrc2]))
    ,FILTER(GLDETAIL,ABS('GLDETAIL'[postingamount])>[MFMinABS])
    ,FILTER('GLDETAIL',GLDETAIL[control]=[MFControl]))
```

In some cases, the `MFControl` measure is `BLANK` because it does not apply. So I need this filter to only apply if the value of `MFControl` is `NOT BLANK`.

Is there a concise way to write this other than the following?

```
TotalMF:=IF(NOT(ISBLANK([MFControl]))
    ,CALCULATE([TotalGLDetail]
        ,FILTER(GLDETAIL,GLDETAIL[concat]=[AnyMFAcct])
        ,FILTER(GLDETAIL,OR(GLDETAIL[journalid]=[MFSrc1],GLDETAIL[journalid]=[MFSrc2]))
        ,FILTER(GLDETAIL,ABS('GLDETAIL'[postingamount])>[MFMinABS])
        ,FILTER('GLDETAIL',GLDETAIL[control]=[MFControl])),CALCULATE([TotalGLDetail]
        ,FILTER(GLDETAIL,GLDETAIL[concat]=[AnyMFAcct])
        ,FILTER(GLDETAIL,OR(GLDETAIL[journalid]=[MFSrc1],GLDETAIL[journalid]=[MFSrc2]))
        ,FILTER(GLDETAIL,ABS('GLDETAIL'[postingamount])>[MFMinABS])
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add more than one condition inside of a filter and you can use an or condition for the last one.

```
TotalMF := 
    CALCULATE([TotalGLDetail],
              FILTER(GLDETAIL,
                     GLDETAIL[concat] = [AnyMFAcct] &&
                     (GLDETAIL[journalid] = [MFSrc1] || GLDETAIL[journalid] = [MFSrc2]) &&
                      ABS('GLDETAIL'[postingamount]) > [MFMinABS] &&
                      (ISBLANK([MFControl]) || GLDETAIL[control] = [MFControl])))
```